# Regex with HttAccess

Tags: redirect, regex

I am trying to use a regex redirect for media, we had them on a cdn but we are moving them back to wordpress.

```
https://res.cloudinary.com/website/image/upload/v........../website/images/
https://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/..../../
https://res.cloudinary.com/startasl/image/upload/website/images/
https://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/website/
Replace:<br>
https://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/
```

We want to have the 4 top directories redirect to the bottom one

we used this, but it did not work.

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/2015/(.*)$ /wp-content/uploads/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/2016/(.*)$ /wp-content/uploads/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/2017/(.*)$ /wp-content/uploads/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/2018/(.*)$ /wp-content/uploads/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/2019/(.*)$ /wp-content/uploads/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Any ideas?